# SharePoint Online Filter By URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, sharepoint

I am working with the SharePoint API and trying to filter search results based on specific URLs. Currently, I have the following search query:

```
http://www.test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Hello%27&trimduplicates=false&sortlist=%27Write:descending%27&rowlimit=5000
```

I want to filter the results from the API based on the following URLs:

```
https://www.test.com/SiteTest
https://www.test.com/Divisions/Academy
https://www.test.com/Divisions/National
```

Is there a specific filter or URL parameter that I can use in the SharePoint API to achieve this? I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to implement this filtering logic.

Comment: [tag:sharepoint] *For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the SharePoint Stack Exchange (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site.* - there's a specific stack exchange for sharepoint development.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Path` property for filtering results from specific sites.

For example, try this:

```
http://www.test.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Hello AND Path:https://www.test.com/SiteTest'&trimduplicates=false&sortlist='Write:descending'&rowlimit=5000
```

**Reference**: [Sharepoint REST - How to search a specific SharePoint site? API calls returning results from all sites I have access to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77680290/sharepoint-rest-how-to-search-a-specific-sharepoint-site-api-calls-returning/77689585#77689585)

Check this for using multiple `Path`: [Sharepoint REST Query with multiple variable for a query tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697540/sharepoint-rest-query-with-multiple-variable-for-a-query-tag)